# Google oAuth with Python for installed app

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth

I'm trying run a "todoist.com" app in Python that uses my Google account to authenticate so I need to get a token from Google first, but I can't figure out how to do that.

I have registered an app at Google, got a client_id, a client_secret and downloaded the JSON code for the app, but I can't figure out how to make the correct calls to get the token.  I have followed the directions here:

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp#choosingredirecturi

But no dice.  My first call is:

```
result = requests.post(auth_uri, data={'response_type': 'code',
                                   'redirect_uri': redirect_URI + ":8000",
                                   'client_id': client_id,
                                   'scope': 'profile',
                                   'state': 'active',
                                   'login_hint': email})
```

...where auth_uri = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"

But the result is always:

```
 <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
```

**502.** That’s an error.

The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.

Please try again in 30 seconds.  That’s all we know.

When I try without the login_hint I get the html for a login page.

Is there a simple script somewhere with a just step-by-step on how to just get the token I need to feed to my third-party API?

Comment: You can get this just at random from Google, from a normally working system, amongst other errors. How long did you try this for?

Comment: I've been trying now for over an hour.  I also just tried again and got the same thing.